# Blink Elements on Pattern

Tags: c++

Got a question regarding Blinking of Elements in C++ in my exam

The Question is
"Print a Star Pattern in C++ and every Star on Even Position in Odd Row of Pattern must Blink"

I've got the code for the Star Pattern and can also identify the Elements on the required positions but I don't have any idea on how to make them Blink.

```
#include<iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void oddline(int* i)
{
     for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
     {

     if(j%2==0)
     {   cout<<"*";     }

     else{

     cout<<"*";//These are the positions which are required to blink.

}
}


int main()
{

  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{  
    if(i%2==0)
    oddline(&i);

    else
    for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
{      cout<<"*";

}
      cout<<endl;
}

}

}
```

Is there any way to make them Blink?

Comment: Clear the screen and rewrite the output with a space instead of a "star"? For the screen-clearing part it's not part of C++ and you have to use OS-specific functionality (functions or terminal control codes).

Comment: I assume with "blink" he means that you should render nothing visible (such as `" "`), so it blinks in and out of existence.

Comment: By "Blink" it means normal blinking, like it constantly appears and disappears

Comment: what platform? mac, windows linux,....

Comment: Since we use windows in our Labs in College it's probably Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the screen coordinates of every line that is printing the stars. Use a  timer to clear and re-print the line(s) to get the desired blinking effect.

Include `windows.h` and use `SetConsoleCursorPosition()` to set the x-y coordinates of your text. This will work only for windows platform.

Try something like this in VC++:

```
#include<chrono>
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>
#include <windows.h>

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    COORD coordinate;
    coordinate.X = x;
    coordinate.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coordinate);
}

void oddline(int i, bool clear)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
            std::cout << "*";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << (clear? " ": "X");
        }
    }
}

void printStars(bool clear = false)
{
    gotoxy(0, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            oddline(i,clear);
        }
        else
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            {
                std::cout << "*";

            }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 50)
    {
        printStars();    // redraw all stars  ( draw only target starts for perf)
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
        printStars(true); // erase target stars
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
        count ++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Edited**

To avoid thread and chrono ( for newbies only) replace sleep_for line with delay():

```
void delay()
{
   int m = 1000; //adjust
   int n = 3200; //adjust
   for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
   {
      for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
         // do nothing
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: do we know OP is on windows?

Comment: I didn't knew about chrono or thread much so I'm studying them right now to get the better understanding of it

Comment: See edited: That line is simply to sleep for 300ms. You can replace it with a nested for loop so that the processing gets delayed by same amount.